# How to best replace link text with Diazo

Tags: xslt, plone, diazo

I want to replace the 'Upcoming Events...' text in the event portlet's footer.  Here is the rule I currently have:

```
<replace content="//dl[contains(@class,'portletEvents')]//dd[contains(@class,'portletFooter')]//a/text()">
    More Events
</replace>
```

This code works, but significantly slows down the site. Can the rule be written better?

Comment: Do you need multi-language support?

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to do it:

```
<replace css:content=".portletEvents .portletFooter a">
    <a>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./@*[contains(' href ', concat(' ', name(), ' '))]"/>
        More events
    </a>
</replace>
```

Comment: Does this work?<replace css:content-children=".portletEvents .portletFooter a">
        More events
    </replace>

Comment: If that's faster, you could use the diazo compiler to see what xpath it generated, then put "/text()" to simplify the replacement.

Comment: @DavidGlick - ha, yes, not sure why I didn't think of that

Comment: @SteveM - I'll look into that, thanks.  
  
It was mentioned in the Plone Developers list that xpath expressions with // can cause speed issues